# Magento2 one checkout page button missing

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have problem with magento checkout page..

After upgrade from magento2.1.8 to Magento2.2.0 i get this issues:

When i add product to cart, if i click to cart, i can't go further, i think that

the cart button is missing from the process page.
[image: Checkout page magento2]

Comment: Check the console for js errors

Comment: I can't find any error  in var/log

Comment: If I disable my  theme, the checkout process button appears again. What can I do?

Comment: So is something in your template or a js error. I mean the browser console for js errors

Comment: The Problem  was with Skrill payment extension. By removing the extension, everything seems to work properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of Skrill (moneybookers) payment extension, by removing the Extension, everything starts to work properly.